# Obtaining correct Joda LocalDateTime values and then formatting them

Tags: java, string-formatting, jodatime

I am trying to run a report every Sunday at midnight that will include data from the previous Saturday at midnight, to 11:59:59 just prior to the report kicking off. Hence, if it were to get kicked off this coming Sunday (2/17), it would:

- Execute at 2/17/2013 at midnight (or Monday morning, however you like to think of it)
- Include data starting at 2/10/2013 12:00:00 AM (last Saturday midnight)
- Include data up to 2/16/2013 11:59:59 PM (this Saturday night, just 1 second prior to the report firing)

I'm trying to obtain a `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` to encapsulate the time range, and want to use a JODA `LocalDateTime` to hold each value. I then need to format them into YYYYMMDD_HHmmss-formatted strings.

Here's my best attempt:

```
LocalDateTime rightNow = new LocalDateTime();
LocalDateTime startDateTime = rightNow.minusDays(7);
LocalDateTime endDateTime = rightNow.minusDays(1);

String startDateTimeFormatted = startDateTime.toString();
String endDateTimeFormatted = endDateTime.toString();

System.out.println(startDateTimeFormatted);
System.out.println(endDateTimeFormatted);
```

When I run this I get:

```
2013-02-06T12:10:27.411
2013-02-12T12:10:27.411
```

**Note**: since I'm running this code today (2/13/2013) the start/end dates are different then they would be on Sunday 2/17 (or any other Sunday), but its the time representation and the String formatting I'm really interested in here.

So I ask:

1. How to get `startDateTime` to represent (for this example - but I need the answer to be dynamic!) 2/10/2013 12:00:00 AM
2. How to get `endDateTime` to represent (for this example - but I need the answer to be dynamic!) 2/16/2013 11:59:59 PM
3. How to format both `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` to appear as 20130210_120000 and 20130216_115959 respectively?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be possible to make the end time exclusive, at which point it would be exactly a week after the start time (and equal to the next start time)? That's generally cleaner - otherwise it's not clear where 11:59:59.999 comes, for example. Also, is there any reason you're using `LocalDateTime` here rather than `DateTime`? The latter would feel more appropriate, given that the report would presumably be based on things that had happened at specific moments in time.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet (+1) - yes I'd be more than happy for the end time to be exclusive, like you said, so that data isn't potentially lost at 11:59:59.999. And no, no preference for `LocalDateTime` or `DateTime`; I've always just used `LocalDateTime` so that's why I put it in the original question, but no preference. Thanks again!

Comment: And one final question before I try to write an answer (although that may not appear very soon, due to other commitments) - do you definitely want this to all happen in the local time zone? Using UTC would give more consistency.

Comment: Yes to UTC @JonSkeet - don't need local timezone. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, as mentioned before, I would strongly recommend using UTC as the time zone, and an exclusive end point. So, you can use:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER =
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd'_'HHmmss")
                  .withLocale(Locale.US);
...

// I prefer to be explicit about using "the current time". I prefer to use
// an injectable dependency such as a Clock type, too...
DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis(), DateTimeZone.UTC);

// Note: this *doesn't* ensure that it's the right day of the week.
// You'd need to think about that separately - it may be as simple as
// scheduling it appropriately... but bear your local time zone in mind!
DateTime end = now.withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime start = end.minusDays(7);

String startText = FORMAT.print(start);
String endText = FORMAT.print(end);
```

Further note that this will use a 24-hour clock, so it would give `20130210_000000` and `20130217_000000` rather than using `120000` as the time. This is far more consistent and unambiguous. Given that it's always midnight though, you might want to just use `yyyyMMdd` and remove the time part entirely.

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println(DateTime.now().toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

the toString method accepts a formatting template, see: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

Comment: It would be better to create a single instance of `DateTimeFormatter` and use that repeatedly though, IMO.

Comment: He mentioned that he wanted a dynamic way of doing formatting, but you are correct if format is not going to change then one DateTimeFormat object is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @AlexChacha (+1) - but what about obtaining the two date/times, where one is at 12:00:00 and the other is at 11:59:59.999?

Comment: "hh:mm:ss" and "hh:mm:ss.SSS" may be what you need.  SSS is the fractional second in the format.